# FBDialogClosePNG.h not found in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been trying to upgrade the Facebook iOS SDK used in my app. I cloned the Git repo and copied everything across to the directory containing the old version, and attempted to build the project. However I get the error `"FBDialogClosePNG.h" file not found`. I can't find that filename anywhere in the repo, or anywhere else through Google. It appears that it is meant to be a wrapper class for an image, since it appears to be called through the following line:

```
UIImage* closeImage = [FBDialogClosePNG image];
```

Does anyone know what we're meant to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

Removing Xcode's DerivedData directory and the generated Pods directory fixed this for me.

`/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/{YourProject}/Pods`

Comment: I was unable to get it to work using this method, despite numerous tries and reinstalls of the pods. Eventually I resorted to restoring the Facebook SDK pod from a backup and manually editing Pod.xcodeproj to put in the files from `AudioResources` and `ImageResources` in the Facebook `src` directory. It'll probably break the next time I do `pod install`, but I couldn't figure out another way.

Answer (score 0):

there is a file in the path `{FB_SDK_DIR}/scripts/image_to_code.py` which will generate a bunch of files including `FBDialogClosePNG.h`.
To get this file, you need to compile facebook's source codes using `src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj` first, then locate the `DerivedSources` folder, put the whole folder into your project.
And you will need a to switch off a lot of compiler warning before your code could compile. Then you should good to go

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because my `Facebook-iOS-SDK` pod didn't get fully updated for whatever reason. I deleted the `Facebook-iOS-SDK` folder from my Pods folder, then ran `pod update` again, and now the problem is fixed.

I was getting lots of missing files: `FBDialogClosePNG.h`, `FBLikeButtonPopWAV.h`, `FBLikeButtonBackgroundPNG.h`, `FBLoginViewButtonPNG.h`, `FBPlacePickerViewGenericPlacePNG.h` and `FBProfilePictureViewBlankProfilePortraitPNG.h`.